# Add a rupee symbol to my gridview column

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, unicode, symbols

I am adding `HeaderText ="Column name"`.

What I want to be is `HeaderText ="Column name [rupee symbol here]"`

I can do a keyboard shortuct of *rupee* ...by installing *rupee* symbol in my system.

Will it be available through all my customers if they didnt install *rupee* symbol in their system?

Or i can do a image column ... by taking a print screen or current column and doing some mspaint works to add rupee symbol and add this ammended image as `GridView` column

is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **Rupee** has a new shape recently (and it has been added to **Unicode 6.0** ) up to now I didn't heard that any international font implement it in their fonts.

So if you want to use new rupee symbol, you have to use its image.

defenit;y if you use the symbol, your customer ( or not all of them ) wont be able to see it in their system.

Youhave to use `TemplateField` to use Image and Label together like

```
<asp:GridView ID="list" runst="server">
    <columns>
        <TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:label ID="Name" runat="Server" Text="Price" />
                <asp:Image ID="rupee" runat="server" ImageURL="Rupee.gif" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:label ID="price" runat="Server" Text="<%# Eval("Price") %>" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        <TemplateField>
    </columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: so yes i can use image , but how i can use image and text together ..do i need to do mspaint edit?

Answer (score 1):

You could custom paint the column header cell ([example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hta8z9sz.aspx)) - and draw the text and image directly on the cell.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed the ASP.net tag, I thought you were in windows forms.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.webrupee.com/font">
```

and in Item Template just write this

```
<span class="WebRupee">Rs</span>
```

You have new rupee sign without Image.